# In Aerospike database, how to show Key when inserting record via aql prompt

Tags: key-value-store, aerospike

I understand, we can make server send the key when sendKey is set in the write policy through some client like Java Client. Can the same be mimicked when inserting record from aql client?

Answer (score 1):

The aql client does not support this functionality. Definitely a good feature request for this command line tool.